# JasperReports: Multiple sub-reports inside a master-report

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I would desperately need some help to achieve the following:

1. Create a master-report.jrxml, which includes a table of content and the corresponding sub-reports
2. These sub-reports all contain a different chart with different data query, which can be bigger than one page
3. Every page which includes a sub-report must show some static frame with dynamic content like the current sub-report's name and page X of Y

My approach so far was, to create a sub-report.jrxml for each of my required charts (I put chart in the sub-report's summary band). Then I created a MasterReport.jrxml with my static frame which included the sub-reports in the summary band. I expected/hoped that JasperReport would render a the according sub-report after each other, but it just overdraws on the same page.

How can I configure my report, to display the sub-reports after each other on new pages?

Any help with this, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: When asking questions, please don't use words like 'desperately', they give a sense of urgency that people who may help don't want to feel. People helps other here in their free time, and need no pressure whatsoever. For what's worth, you may read this: [link](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#urgent). Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with subReports in a detail band and subRepport element has "Run to bottom" property which, if set to true, will make subReport take the whole page and push next item on a new page. There is also a page break element in JasperReports if "Run to bottom" doesn't work for you . For static content on each page use page header/footer bands.

Comment: When I put the sub-reports in the detail band (of the master-report), JasperStudio runs into infinite loop when previewing the report... do I need change something else? Thanks!

Comment: The infinite loop disappeared after I removed the queryExpression "select * from dual" from my master-report. But now I don't see any of my sub-reports.

Comment: Try "select 1 as test from dual", you should get only one row.

Comment: Ah, I also had to change the layout of my detail band to "Vertical Layout", then it renders correctly. Thanks for your help.